# How to round number in javascript if number has 0.04500001 as decimals?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, numbers, rounding

I came across a number like this in a project :

[image: Number]

I was wondering whats the case for rounding up this kind of number in real world project and how to round the number when it has lots of zeros like this :

```
 {item.size - item.filled}
```

I also tried `toFixed` but it applies it to all generated numbers so other numbers which aren't in the format like this one , will also get zeros after decimals.

```
{(item.size - item.filled).toFixed(7)}
```

How can I round this kind of number only If it's like this and what would be the normal scenario in a real world project ? Should we just not display all the zeros in decimals ?

Comment: Rounding this will give you 0.0538 in any case.
What do you expect finally??? 
I posted an answer but I don't know if this can solve Your issue...
If you remove all the zeros the number will not be representative at all!
Add some details about what You expect please!
Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I wrote an answer to format all sort of rounding...

Possible duplicate with "I'd like to round at most two decimal places, but only if necessary"...

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/how-to-round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-if-necessary/73831129#73831129](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/how-to-round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-if-necessary)

This answer do the job : You can round Your number at any decimal and add "0" to obtain the format You want to reach.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>roundPrecision</title>
    <script>
        class MyMath{
            static roundPrecision(number,precision,fillZeros){
                    // number You want to round
                    // precision nb of decimals
                    // fillZeros the number of 0 You want to add IF necessary!
                    // 0 = no fill with zeros.
                    let num = number;
                    let prec = precision;
                    let exp = Math.pow(10,prec);
                    let round = Math.round(number * exp)/exp
                    if (fillZeros>0){
                        return round.toFixed(fillZeros)
                        }
                    return round;
                }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p class="myMath" id="field1"></p>
    <p class="myMath" id="field2"></p>
    <p class="myMath" id="field3"></p>
    <p class="myMath" id="field4"></p>
    <p class="myMath" id="field5"></p>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("field1").innerHTML = MyMath.roundPrecision(5,0,3); // 5.000
        document.getElementById("field2").innerHTML = MyMath.roundPrecision(Math.PI,2,4); // 3.1400
        document.getElementById("field3").innerHTML = MyMath.roundPrecision(2.4,1,2); // 2.40
        document.getElementById("field4").innerHTML = MyMath.roundPrecision(2.9,0,2);   // 3.00
        document.getElementById("field5").innerHTML = MyMath.roundPrecision(10,0,2); // 10.00
    </script>
</body>
</html>

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In this case MyMath.roundPrecision([Your number],17,0); will give You [Your number]. 
Let me know...

Answer (score 0):

I am always displaying two decimals, your number is a Javascript problem.
I use this function to round it:

```
 export const roundNumberToTwoDecimals = (number) =>
    Math.round(number * 100 + Number.EPSILON) / 100;
```